# Pass URL variables and use it for queries

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The initial flow of the app is like this:

1. User clicks a `language`
2. Url fires a GET request based on the `id` of the `language` given
3. Returns and displays all `frameworks` that are related to the given `language`

Without DRF, it would look something like this:

**views.py**:

```
def frameworks_from_language(request, language_id):
    language = Language.objects.get(pk=language_id)

    if language == None:
        # Do some stuffs

    frameworks = language.framework_set.all()
    template = 'app/language.html'
    context = {
        'frameworks': frameworks
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

And in **urls.py**:

```
path('language/<int:language_id>', views.frameworks_from_language, name='getframeworks')
```

This would return a template with an object `frameworks` that you could just simply display in a for-loop. However I have no idea on how to do something like this on DRF.

I tried this (as suggested by a friend):

**serializers.py**

```
class LanguageRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ('frameworks',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'frameworks': {
                'source': 'framework_set',
                'many': True
            }
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class SelectedLanguageViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LanguageRelationSerializer
```

And in **urls.py**

```
router.register('selected-language', views.SelectedLanguageViewSet)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It would just display something like this:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "frameworks": [
                3
            ]
        },
        {
            "frameworks": [
                2
            ]
        },
        {
            "frameworks": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I haven't even given some parameters in the url or something.

Any ideas/example on how to pass url params in DRF and then later on use them on views?

Comment: Hi @Dran I think you want to try POST method in which you have to pass value of id and you can use that value in your views.

Comment: Hello @VaibhavMishra thanks for the heads up! Can you give me an example/tutorial link for it? I tried something on my own but it didn't worked :<

Comment: Your url arguments (ex: language_id) are passed to the view as kwargs. They can be accessed in the view: self.kwargs[‘language_id’]. You need to write a get_queryset method and you can access the kwargs there.

Answer (score 1):

By using `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` `django-rest-framework` already generates `^selected-language/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='language-detail']` for You thanks to [`RetrieveModelMixin`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrievemodelmixin).

It uses `GenericAPIView.get_object()` which finds `Language` instance by `lookup_field` (`pk` in your case).

So you can jus use `selected-language/1` to get `Language` with `id=1`, without pagination.